# GItlab does not send email on new issue

Tags: gitlab

GItlab does not send email on new issue, but do it for issue closing and comments. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any notification rule issue on GitLab are referenced ("featured") in [Issue 2669](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2669).
A redesign is in progress ([issue 1808](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1808)), but not there yet.

Proposals already exists ([issue 2466](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2466), [issue 1448](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1448) ), where you can select the people in a team you want to be notified:

[image: email selection]

That feature request is managed here: "[Improve email/notification system](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3726325-improve-email-notification-system)".